# How to upload a file to a server via FTP using R?

Tags: r, file-upload, ftp

How to upload a file to a server via FTP using R?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(RCurl)
ftpUpload("Localfile.html", "ftp://User:Password@FTPServer/Destination.html")
```

Where `Localfile.html` is the file to be uploaded, `User` indicates the user name and `Password` the password to log into the server while `FTPServer` is a placeholder for the server name and possible path to use while last but not least `Destination.html` is an example of the name the to be uploaded file gets on the server.

Comment: Is there any way to upload directly from r global environment without saving it ( for example - tableData <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                        b = c(1, 4, 4, 8)
                        )

ftpUpload(tableData,
          "ftp://ftp.blahblah/tableData.csv",
          userpwd = "user:pass"
          )

Comment: This might work: `ftp_upload <- 
  function(df, dest, user, pass, server, protocol = "ftp"){
    fname <- tempfile()
    write.csv(df)
    RCurl::ftpUpload(
      what = fname, 
      glue::glue("{protocol}://{user}:{pass}@{server}/{dest}")
    )
  }` ... but I do not have a way to test that anymore

Answer (score 9):

Your best bet may be the [RCurl](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RCurl) package. From the DESCRIPTION:

> [...] 
>   Additionally, the
>   underlying implementation is robust
>   and extensive, supporting
>   FTP/FTPS/TFTP (*uploads and downloads*),

Otherwise, rethink your problem.  Maybe HTTP POST will do as well.  It's not 1986 anymore so you're not required to use ftp.

Comment: Thanks Dirk - it sounds an interesting direction to checkout

Answer (score 3):

If you can access it from the command line, then you can do:

```
system("ftp ...") # where ... is the argument list
```

You could easily wrap this in an R function if you plan on doing it often.

Comment: Becomes a pain with authentication and all that as how those things are handled is platform-dependent.  Hence my call for RCurl...

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but I solve my sharing problems by moving the file to my Public dropbox folder and link to that in my R code.

My two pennies.