# Setting Directory

Tags: r, directory

I am wondering if it is possible to set web site, http or ftp, as a directory on R.

I found a similar question, and it suggests using `RCurl`, `curlOption`. I did not find that kind of command. Perhaps I am misunderstanding his comments.

If I can set directory, I want to set here: `ftp://amrc.ssec.wisc.edu/pub/aws/10min/rdr/`

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620426/how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-server-via-ftp-using-r

Comment: Basically I am trying to find the way to download fast from the website I put link above. There are thousands of data, but I just need few...

Comment: You cannot use `setwd` with a URL. You are better off using `wget` or `curl` from a Windows, Mac or Linux shell to grab the files then process them with R.

Comment: You could open a `?connection` to a site and download files from it with `download.file`, or even just read what you need with `readLines` (in some cases).

Comment: RCurl is an optional package in CRAN that needs to be installed and loaded before you can use any of its functions. I have not knowledge about curloptions; it's not on CRAN.

Comment: Thank you for all comments!