# Can I save my R output (.jpeg) to an FTP server?

Tags: r, ftp, powerbi, rcurl

*(optional read)* Greater Objective: PowerBI Web [doesn't support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-r-packages-support) a few R packages when published on the internet. It throws the below error ("Missing R Package"). Hence, I am working towards saving the output from R as an image (.jpeg) to a remote location (*such as FTP*) or cloud storage (secure and open source) and then import it to PowerBI. This workaround might resolve the package conflict (*hoping*).

[image]

**Specific Objective***: The below code illustrates a trivial way of saving an R output(.jpeg) image locally. However, is there a way to save the image directly to the FTP server, provided I have the username/password etc? (*unfortunately, I cannot share the server details*)

```
library(outbreaks)
library(incidence)

cases = subset(nipah_malaysia, select = c("perak", "negeri_sembilan", "selangor",
                                           "singapore"))

i = as.incidence(cases, dates = nipah_malaysia$date, interval = 7L)
jpeg(file = "plot.jpeg")
plot(i)
dev.off()
```

I did come across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620426/how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-server-via-ftp-using-r) on employing `ftpUpload` function from the `"rcurl"` package. However, to upload it to FTP, I might still need to save it locally which defeats my purpose in this use-case.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Is there a way to use `tempfile` and then push it to FTP, instead of saving the plot locally?

Comment: I generally discourage FTP in favor of SSH (which can provide a ftp-like interface). You can use the [`ssh`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ssh/index.html) package to `scp_upload` a file.

Comment: Any other recommendations where I can temporarily save the image on remote or cloud-based storage and import it to PowerBI?

Comment: Have you considered using https://pastebin.com/? @hrbrmstr has an R package for it, aptly named [`pastebin`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/pastebin), I believe it is not yet on CRAN. (Caveat: I've never used it, and it's been a few years since he's pushed to that repo, not sure if it's maintained/functioning. I've done no testing.)

Comment: I suppose it is limited to text. [Ref.](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/pastebin)

Comment: You can serialize, but you're right. Perhaps imgur is useful?

Answer (score 1):

If saving a temporary file (as you suggested in a comment) is an option, then you can do that with the following code:

```
library(outbreaks)
library(incidence)
library(RCurl)

cases = subset(nipah_malaysia, select = c("perak", "negeri_sembilan", "selangor",
                                           "singapore"))

i = as.incidence(cases, dates = nipah_malaysia$date, interval = 7L)
jpeg(file = filename <- tempfile())
plot(i)
dev.off()
ftpUpload(filename, "ftp://User:Password@FTPServer/destfile.jpeg")
```

Comment: Correct. However, I learnt that 'tempfile' is eventually stored locally. If the code that imports an image runs on PowerBI web, it won't be able to navigate to local storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with having the output in PNG format (EDIT: I updated the code to show output to JPEG format) try the code below, with chunks borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171523/in-r-how-to-plot-into-a-memory-buffer-instead-of-a-fileinstead-of-a-file) that discusses how to save an image in memory:

EDIT: Updated to output to jpeg format

```
library(outbreaks)
library(incidence)

cases = subset(nipah_malaysia, select = c("perak", "negeri_sembilan", "selangor",
                                          "singapore"))

orig_i = as.incidence(cases, dates = nipah_malaysia$date, interval = 7L)
plot(orig_i)

#### This section adapted from
#### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171523/in-r-how-to-plot-into-a-memory-buffer-instead-of-a-fileinstead-of-a-file
#### loads image data to memory rather than a file

library(Cairo)
library(png)
library(ggplot2)

Cairo(file='/dev/null')

plot(orig_i) #your plot

# hidden stuff in Cairo
i = Cairo:::.image(dev.cur())
r = Cairo:::.ptr.to.raw(i$ref, 0, i$width * i$height * 4)

dev.off()

dim(r) = c(4, i$width, i$height) # RGBA planes
# have to swap the red & blue components for some reason
r[c(1,3),,] = r[c(3,1),,]

# now use the jpeg library to write the raw vector
library(jpeg)
p = writeJPEG(r, raw()) # raw JPEG bytes

#DEBUGGING - check that this actually works
#Note: Windows 10 has an error that might report this as a file system error
#In windows, drag and drop the file into an open chrome window to see the image
writeBin(p, con= "yourpathhere/check_output.jpg")


#adapted code from @tfehring's example for the updload
library(RCurl)
ftpUpload(p, "ftp://User:Password@FTPServer/destfile.jpg")
```